# Rendering issues with CEFSharp

Tags: wpf, extjs, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a WPF application that just hosts a browser using CefSharp in version 81. Inside that browser I run a Ext.js web application. Currently I'm experiencing some weird behavior from time to time that elements in may application are not properly display (elements overlap or do not have the correct height). This issues only occur from time to time and after restarting the application everything is fine again. My best guess is that this must be somehow related to CEFSharp. Did anybody experience similar things or has an idea what the cause of this might be?

Comment: Maybe you have memory leaks or some bugs which crashes app layout. Only God knows why..

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with version 83.4.20? Do you have a sample that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch the error if it takes place in your app, something like:

```
// message, url, lineNumber
window.onerror = function(m,u,l) {
   //Send this data to server or alert them..
    return true
};
```